# how to crawl or how to get all elements from a URL using JSOUP and java, first login the page, then crawl the page after the login

Tags: java, authentication, url, web-crawler, jsoup

I have to crawl the elements in the index page, to do that, I have to log in then navigate to the index page, how to solve this using Jsoup and Java.

Step 1: Login: (how to connect my user name and password with the fields inside the login page).
Step 2: After successful login, navigate to the index page, then crawl said elements inside the index page.

Comment: http://joelmin.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-login-to-website-using-jsoup-java_4.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login using Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734840/login-using-jsoup)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can fetch the index page with cookie. To fetch cookie, Press F12 after login using your browser.

Comment: how to send the cookie details to the index page