# Getting text on jsoup?

Tags: android, kotlin, jsoup

I recently was referred to jsoup and I am trying to retrieve a string from a Google Script API link that feeds me a single string. However, I am unable to retrieve it. When I do

```
val ipadd: String = doc.body()
```

I do not seem to see my string inside. I have also tried

```
val ipadd: String = doc.getElementsContainingText("L1").toString()
```

but it didn't work either. If anyone could provide some help, that would be great. I have put the url for the Google Script API below. Thanks.
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyjRIRl2ca_pnfz8XgccjDlaRPUNz6KY_WcyPZAROsy9EZkD35F/exec?command=GetLock1IPAddress

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a value through Google Service. Since you are asked to "authenticate", you cannot get that value because you cannot access the corresponding value. When I test it with Jsoup individually, you will encounter a related error.

Sample questions are shared to discuss the "auth" process.

[Sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734840/login-using-jsoup)

[Sample 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403851/logging-into-a-website-jsoup)

[Sample Code Google Service Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667090/jsoup-library-in-java-logging-on-google)

Comment: I have set the google script api to be used by anyone though?